# What is terminal set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone explain in a simple way what is terminal set?

I've read the definition:
We define `i` is a singleton set.
For any set A, there exists a function `A → i` which is unique: that is, there exists exactly one function from `A` to `i`. We call such a set `i` as terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I$ is a singleton set $\{*\}$, i.e. it consists of one element. It is by definition called terminal set. Indeed, for any other set $A$ we have unique function $a\to I$ that maps any element $a\in A$ to the element $*\in I$.

Comment: How can I prove it using set properties? Can you, please, help by giving hints?

Comment: By definition, function $A\to i$ is a rule of sending each element of $A$ to an element of $i$. But $i$ has only one element, so there   can be only one such rule, namely, that sends every element of $A$ to the element $*$.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, in a category an object $A$ is called *initial object* if for every object $X$ there exists *exactly* one morphism $A\to X$ and $A$ is called *terminal object* if for every object $X$ there exists *exactly* one morphism $X\to A$.

For the category of sets, the only initial object is the empty set $\emptyset$ and every set with exactly one element is terminal. That is exactly what they are trying to tell you.

Comment: I don't think using categories will help someone who have just started to learn basic set theory. I mean, knowledge that is required to understand your answer is more than the knowledge, required to understand the original problem.